# is it possible to get a sticky window with the interface implementors in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

So, I can get a popup displaying the implementors of a particular interface. But it is a popup, it is closed if I click outside of it. What I want is a sticky window, like one in Eclipse or even the one ReSharper gives in VS.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While standing on the interface class use `Navigate` | **Type Hierarchy** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>). Hierarchy panel will open and stick on the side when **Pinned**.

Comment: Alt+H in Visual Studio mapping.